# Swapping values in different rows in SQL table

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a table as below

```
Column 1  Column 2 

 A    10000
 A    20000
 B    10000
 B    30000
 C    20000
 C    50000
```

How do I reverse the Column 2 values with grouping on Column 1 using SQL like below?

```
A    20000
A    10000
B    30000
B    10000
C    50000
C    20000
```

Comment: Do you have any other columns in your table? If not, the results are identical.

Comment: `ORDER BY Column1, Column2 DESC` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to update the columns

Comment: I do have other columns in the table, some are identical in both rows, some are not.

Comment: Post more realistic data and the desired result.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Your "reordering" actually means nothing in terms of the underlying data, because the set of rows is the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of "order" in RDBMS tables, so "switching" the rows is meaningless. If you want the rows from your table presented in a certain order, just query it accordingly with an `order by` clause:

```
SELECT   a, b
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC
```